# Get order count of employees, which have different count than in one city

Tags: sql, join, group-by, count, window-functions

SQL studying is going good speed forward. Now got practice where I need some help.

I would like to get names of the employees who have different count of orders than employees in New York.

Tables:

`ORDERS`, which including `EMPLOYEE_ID, CITY, ORDER_ID`

`EMPLOYEES`, which including `LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID, CITY`

I have been stuck in this situation:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY COUNT(T.ORDER_ID) DESC) ROW,
(H.LAST_NAME + ', ' + H.FIRST_NAME) 'Employee name',
COUNT(T.ORDER_ID) 'Sold orders', H.CITY 'City'

FROM ORDERS T JOIN EMPLOYEE H ON T.EMPLOYEE_ID = H.EMPLOYEE_ID

GROUP BY H.EMPLOYEE_ID, H.LAST_NAME, H.FIRST_NAME, H.CITY
```

With that I can get orders which employees has sold. Unfortunately it does not show employees with 0 orders.

How I can show also employees with 0 orders? And how can I show employees who have different count of orders than employees in one city? Example employees which have different order coutn than employees in New York.

I hope you understand what I mean. Complicated problem and little language barrier.

Example data:

```
First_name    Last_name    Sold_orders    City
John          Doe          2              New York
Jane          Doe          5              Los Angeles
Peter         Pan          5              Miami
```

I would like to get employees which do not have same count of orders than employees in Miami.

```
First_name    Last_name    Sold_orders    City
John          Doe          2              New York
```

So Jane doe and Peter Pan has gone, because they have same count of orders than employees in Miami (Miami itself included).

Comment: 1. Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful. 2. Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: @Yougesh Sharma Thanks for the tip! I can not see DBMS what I am using. It is school version and all info hided. I'll make results example.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you just want a `left join`. For this you need to start from the `employee` table, then bring the `orders`.

```
select 
    row_number() over ( order by count(o.order_id) desc) rn,
    e.last_name + ', ' + e.first_name employee_name,
    count(o.order_id) sold_orders, 
    e.city
from employee e
left join orders o on o.employee_id = e.employee_id
group by e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.first_name, e.city
```

Note that I also changed the column aliases: you should avoid using single quotes. Although some databases allow this, single quotes are usually meant for string litterals rather than identifiers. Databases use different symbols to quote identifiers (Oracle and Postgres have double quotes, MySQL has backticks, SQL Server has square brackets). I changed the query so it uses identifiers that do not require quotes.

Comment: Thanks now it's showing zero orders also. How would I get employees who have different count of orders than employees in specified city? And thanks of the tip of single quotes. In future I use ```AS``` or like you did. Thanks!